# opuslib decoding fails with "corrupt stream" on the opus header packet

Tags: python, audio, opus

I have a valid ogg audio file (works in several players including [opus-tools opusdec](https://opus-codec.org/release/dev/2018/09/18/opus-tools-0_2.html); ffmpeg correctly identifies the file and reports no problems). The audio stream has two channels, a sample rate of 48kHz, and a 20ms frame duration.

You can recreate a very similar file using ffmpeg

```bash
ffmpeg -i "a media file with audio" \
-f opus -frame_duration 20 -ar 48000 -ac 2 \
audio.ogg
```

In a hex editor, I was able to extract the first Opus packet/segment/frame according to the [Ogg file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg#File_format).

Here it is:
`4F 70 75 73 48 65 61 64 01 02 38 01 80 BB 00 00 00 00 00`

[image: hex editor screenshot of opus packet in ogg file]

Then, I attempt to use [libopus v1.4](https://opus-codec.org/release/stable/2023/04/20/libopus-1_4.html) (via the [opuslib](https://pypi.org/project/opuslib/) Python bindings) to begin decoding the stream:

```py
from opuslib import Decoder

SAMPLE_RATE = 48000  # hertz
FRAME_DURATION = 20  # milliseconds
FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 1000 // FRAME_DURATION
SAMPLES_PER_FRAME = SAMPLE_RATE // FRAMES_PER_SECOND
CHANNELS = 2
SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL_FRAME = SAMPLES_PER_FRAME // CHANNELS

packet = bytes.fromhex("4F 70 75 73 48 65 61 64 01 02 38 01 80 BB 00 00 00 00 00")

decoder = Decoder(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS)
result = decoder.decode(packet, SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL_FRAME)

print(result)
```

Which produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\test.py", line 50, in <module>
    result = decoder.decode(packet, SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL_FRAME)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\site-packages\opuslib\classes.py", line 56, in decode
    return opuslib.api.decoder.decode(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\site-packages\opuslib\api\decoder.py", line 246, in decode
    raise opuslib.exceptions.OpusError(result)
opuslib.exceptions.OpusError: b'corrupted stream'
```

I have tried multiple variations of the `CONSTANT` calculations.
I have tried decoding the second packet, the third packet, the first and second packet concatenated, etc.
All to no avail.

I get the same error for every ogg file I test. What am I doing wrong?

I'm on Windows 11 and built `libopus` from source using the included VS .sln files with preset ReleaseDLL_fixed x64.

Comment: Hopefully it's obvious that I don't intend on manually extracting every packet from the Ogg container in a hex editor... I already have the working code to do that. I didn't share it here to avoid complicating the question.

Comment: "In a hex editor, I was able to extract the first Opus packet/segment/frame" - in your own words, why do you expect that this is what should be passed to `Decoder.decode`? Did you consider the possibility that it's expecting the header? If not, why not? Did you try reading the documentation? "I have tried decoding the second packet, the third packet, the first and second packet concatenated, etc. All to no avail." Did you try anything that starts with the header?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I expect this to be passed to `decode` because this is the first piece of information which is encoded, so logically it should be the first thing decoded. The parameter is documented as "Input payload. Use a NULL pointer to indicate packet loss" which implies that we should pass each packet here. The first packet _is_ the header. We know this because it contains the magic "OpusHead".  Passing the Ogg header would be complete nonsense since the codec has nothing to do with that. I've tried both with and without this header packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of two issues, which are masking each other.

1. The `libopus` decoder does not care about the headers, both `OpusHead` and `OpusTags`. Simply do not pass those packets to the decoder.
2. The `frame_size` parameter is *not* per-channel.

Overall, you decode an Opus packet like so:

```py
for packet in opus_packet_iterator():
  if packet.startswith((b"OpusHead", b"OpusTags")):
    process_header_packet(packet)
  else:
    pcm_data = decoder.decode(packet, SAMPLES_PER_FRAME)
    process_pcm_data(pcm_data)
```